# Jump to node documentation in vim

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim

All,

I've recently started doing some javascript coding. I have used the [python-mode vim plugin](https://github.com/klen/python-mode), and I was looking for a javascript plugin with similar functionality.

I've got most of the important stuff already, so the thing I would most like is a plugin that can jump directly to the docs for a library built in. In python-mode, this is done by putting the cursor on a function call and pressing `D`. It opens a new split with the contents of the doc.

Cursory google searching does not reveal anything similar for javascript/node.js so I would like to know if there is something available, or if I need to roll my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If bringing the documentation up in a browser works for you, I created a Vim plugin called [dochub.vim](https://github.com/stephenmckinney/vim-dochub).

It will bring up documentation for CSS, DOM, HTML, JavaScript, JQuery, PHP, and Python by placing the cursor over a class, property, or method and typing `JJ`.

Comment: Dochub seems a little slow, but otherwise this seems close enough. I do wish it could open a file with the definition in the current project for new functions, but that has problems.

Comment: Yes, Dochub has a lot of AJAXiness that falls on its face sometimes. I've thought of pointing the script at https://developer.mozilla.org but I don't see an easy way to search it like dochub. dochub basically ingests Mozilla's docs and makes it easily searchable. If you know an alternative I'll update the plugin.

Comment: I misspoke. Mozilla docs are easily searchable, but not *jumpable*. I like that Dochub takes me straight to class or property I'm interested in without having  to look over 10 or so search results.

Comment: That is a nice feature. I haven't used the plugin yet, so we'll see if the slow loading is a problem in practice.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing for JavaScript, I'm afraid.

Python-mode uses Python's built-in `help('keyword')` but I'm not aware of such a thing in any JavaScript engine. Not even nodejs. I'd like to be proven wrong, though.

You could come up with something that calls `https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/search?q=Date` when the cursor is on `Date()`. But I don't think it's realistic to expect more.

Did you look [over there](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=javascript&script_type=utility&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search)?

Comment: That's a shame. Ah well, I'd hoped to be surprised.

Comment: When you do find a program to display your documentation you may want to checkout `:h keywordprg` and `:h K`. Then append the something like `setlocal keywordprg js-man` to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/js.vim`